# How to set div to 100% width with padding without overflow

Tags: html, css

When addind a css of something like

```css
#mydiv {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red; /* only for visualization*/
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" >my div<div/>
```

It will overflow the page.

How can I make this "100 percentage width" not overflow because of the padding?

I don't want to hide the overflow, but I want to make the width a little less than `100%` but without having to hardcode some width.

Something like `width: 100% - padding`

Answer (score 2):

Add box-sizing: border-box to the div's css

Answer (score 0):

By using calc, you can remove the padding from 100%

```css
#mydiv {
    width: calc(100% - 40px)
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red; /* only for visualization*/
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" >my div<div/>
```

Comment: He added padding for all 4 sides, it will not work as you have written.

Comment: Did you run the code? Isn't it working as expected? Can you describe the problem?

Answer (score 0):

use just

```
 width: auto;
```

no need to provide 100% it is by default uses full.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If div contain display property as Block no need to give width 100%, else add display property as block or flex

```
width:auto;
display:block;
```

else

```
display:flex;
```